# Fill an array with random numbers in correct way with sum of every four equals or higher than two

Tags: java, arraylist, random, java-stream

I need some help or hint. There is a code:

```
public class RandomInArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] array = random.ints(8, 0, 2).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

**example: [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]**

The Sum of every 4 numbers in an array has to be a minimum of 2.
example: [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]
From first 1+0+1+0 is correct, the sum is >=2.
than:
0,1,0,0, the sum is 1. Incorrect.
1,0,0,1, the sum is 2. Correct.
0,1,0,1, the sum is 2. Correct.
How to extend method to print out every time correct random mix of elements in array?
There are correct examples with 8 elements. If ex. 20 elements, less or more, the result should be the same.
Correct examples:

```
[1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
[1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1]
[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: What does the sentence “If ex. 20 elements, less or more, the result should be the same” mean?

Comment: Hi, it means the solution with 8 elements in array is fine for me on this moment but if I want to extend the list to over 8 elements to 20 for example, it should work too.

Comment: I suggest to write it into the question the way you just explained it to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a condition on random numbers then they are no longer random.  You could generate the first two numbers at random, and then use a more limited set of options to pick the next two.

- (0, 0) must be followed by (1, 1)
- (0, 1) or (1, 0) can be followed by (0, 1) or (1, 0)
- (1, 1) can be followed by (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0) or (1, 1)

Then shift your frame by 1 and look at the last three already chosen numbers.  The sum of those three will limit the possibilities for the next number.